# Javascript .mask() masked input multiple optionals

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, mask

Im using javascript plugin masked input.

my current code is:

```
 $("#a").mask("9?9999", {"placeholder": ""}); //so other 4 9999 are optional
```

what i want to achieve is something like this:

```
 $('#a').mask("9?9999?.99?9", {"placeholder": ""});
```

i want a user to be able to type the following:

```
    5 //valid
    7.99 //valid
    7712.239 //valid
```

is there a way of achieving this with .mask() ? i tried the above code but didnt seem to work.

Comment: My practice shows that validating the for on submit is the best way ... The user should be notified to enter the number in format needed ... The user can change many times his input but on submit you will check his final decision. In my oppinion masking fields is not a good practice.

Comment: for this project i need to specifically use masking thats why im stuck

Comment: you could do your own validation `.onchange` ... will save your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the simple answer is no.

maybe you could look at the [jquery.numeric](http://www.texotela.co.uk/code/jquery/numeric/) plugin, which is specific for numeric input box.